# I Need Help With Human Degenerative Disease (HDD)

Tags: science-based, biology, post-apocalypse, diseases, behaviour

I am currently working on a post-apocalyptic world where roughly 90% of humanity get infected by HDD (Human Degenerative Disease). HDD causes the human brain, glands and tissues to change quite dramatically. Reducing the majority of the infected to a feral state in which they are no longer sapient, but can be trained (with effort) similarly to gorillas, chimpanzees and dogs. The infected breed true among themselves, seem to have no memories of their past lives, and over the past 50 years have propagated a great deal. An immune or uninfected person who breeds with one of these new ferals has a 75% chance of producing non-feral offspring.

I am wondering what sorts of behavioural traits these ferals would be likely to exhibit and adopt?

Looking up info on Feral Children has not proven useful. The ferals in this case would still live among their own kind albeit adapted to living as wild animals. I suspect that they would act similarly to other Old World primates but I'd appreciate a second opinion.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, as you have guessed, it would be helpful if you could narrow it down.

Comment: This really does need to be narrowed down and the scope of perspective answers defined; you've floated *psychic abilities* as a potential outcome, which doesn't help.

Comment: Is this an *infection* or a spontaneous genetic mutation?  These are very different things that do not overlap.  There are no infections with the genetic effects you imply.  Though with magic/etc, you can make up anything you want.  And yes, narrow it down!

Comment: Please read our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654). The problem with questions like this is they are not objective and you've provided no criteria for judging a best answer. Please remember that [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).

Comment: Hi Jeremy! You're still asking two questions here. (Behaviours is one; interactions in another.) And both are still a bit broad. Your edit is helpful, but perhaps not sweeping enough in scope!

Comment: @elemtilas Okay thanks. I shall edit more later.

Comment: No worries!  Keep in mind: you can always a follow-up query focusing on the other aspect!

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific about what causes this disease? It is hard to determine its effects without knowing its causes.

Comment: Hi @Obelisk! So, it looks like your query might need further narrowing. You might want to focus your query on one aspect of feral behaviour. Several come to mind immediately: shelter, finding food, finding water, group/tribal dynamics. Being a post-pockyclyptic scenario, I'd wager that most of the newly infected people who regress to a feral state will suffer horribly in the wild. Humans aren't especially instinct driven anymore: we have to learn how to hunt, how to make shelter, how to live in society. Pick an aspect like one of these and go with that. (cont...)

Comment: ... Also, I'm not sure "HDD" is the term you're looking for here. That is a very broad grouping of diseases whose manifestations include degenerative processes. Alzheimers, Lou Gehrigs, Parkinsons, MS, Tay-Sachs -- these are all degenerative diseases. I could be wrong, but I think you mean something else by "degenerative" than is usually understood in medicine. You seem to be focused on social degeneration. If so, perhaps you could consider an edit to clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the fantasy races as a starting point

perhaps the mutations reflect peoples subconscious fears and desires for their current situations and personalities

there were humans who went underground to escape the deasise, but got infected anyways, becoming dwarfs, with more hardy bodies to operate the last working machines and tanks.

perhaps vampires could be former doctors and nurses, who immediately after the collapse were in extreme starvation, forced to consume blood, afterwards amassing power by controlling precious medicine, and antibiotics

hobbits are those who lived in small agricultural communities such as the Amish, and those who lived in the rural areas of third world countries.

the first infected you described could be orcs, who fighting for scavenged cans of food and small game would be selected for large musles, and hunched heads to minimize the killing power of sneak attacks to the back of the head.

The people who became psychics could be the elves with the side effect of having less dense bones, as they feel the need to escape quickly from the din of the cities, newly amplifeyed by their heightened senses

a repurposed high tech aircraft carrier that was sent out to sea, to harbor high ranking government officials could see its inhabitants gain the ability to breath water to repair the ship and forage for food, becoming Atlantians.

anyways I'm not saying you should make it a fantasy story, just that this is how I thought up the races.

also I'm new to this stack exchange, and I wrote this over some time, so if you have any questions or criticisms, please ask